# Issue executing MR programs on Hadoop from Eclipse

Tags: hadoop, eclipse-plugin

I am having problem executing mapreduce program from eclipe on my `windows` to the `hadoop` `Pseudo cluster` running on `Ubuntu VM` running on same machine.

I am running `hadoop 1.0.3`. I tried with `eclipse Juno` as well `Ganymede` with `eclipse` `plugin 1.0.3`, but no success. I get connection error whenever I add my `Linux VM` as a mapreduce location.

I also tried setting the properties directly through configuration like below, with no further luck. I run this as a `java application`.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://192.168.65.132:8020/");
conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "192.168.65.132:8021");
conf.set("hadoop.job.ugi", "hadoop");
```

I get the following error.

```
13/01/08 09:59:44 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.65.132/192.168.65.132:8020. Already tried 7 time(s).
13/01/08 09:59:46 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.65.132/192.168.65.132:8020. Already tried 8 time(s).
13/01/08 09:59:48 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.65.132/192.168.65.132:8020. Already tried 9 time(s).
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Call to 192.168.65.132/192.168.65.132:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information

at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1099)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1075)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
at $Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:379)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:119)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:238)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:203)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:89)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:123)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:238)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.addInputPath(FileInputFormat.java:372)
at inverika.training.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:37)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:599)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:489)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:434)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:560)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2000(Client.java:184)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1206)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1050)
... 17 more
```

Has any one tried similar set up? Please share your experience on this.

Netstat dump:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address   Foreign Address State 
tcp6  0      0      127.0.0.1:8020  :::*            LISTEN 
tcp6  0      0      127.0.0.1:8021  :::*            LISTEN 
tcp6  0      0      127.0.0.1:58399 127.0.0.1:8020  ESTABLISHED 
tcp6  0      0      127.0.0.1:8020  127.0.0.1:58399 ESTABLISHED 
tcp6  0      0      127.0.0.1:45042 127.0.0.1:8021  ESTABLISHED 
tcp6  0      0      127.0.0.1:8021  127.0.0.1:45042 ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Can you perform a `netstat -atn` in a terminal and conform that your JT and NN are running on the ports specified (8020 & 8021)

Comment: Hi Chris, Here is the output from the command
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8020          :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8021          :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:58399         127.0.0.1:8020          ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8020          127.0.0.1:58399         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:45042         127.0.0.1:8021          ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8021          127.0.0.1:45042         ESTABLISHED

Answer (score 0):

From the netstat, it looks like your pseudo vm is only going to accept connections from itself (the VM). I would expect the netstat entries for the NN and JT to look more like this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address   Foreign Address State 
tcp   0      0      0.0.0.0:8020    :::*            LISTEN 
tcp   0      0      0.0.0.0:8021    :::*            LISTEN
```

I'm not sure that the proto being tcp6 should matter, but the local addresses should show up as 0.0.0.0:[port] if you want to connect to them externally. 127.0.0.1 is a loopback address, so connections will only be accepted from the VM itself.

You also need to look at how your VM network is configured (NAT, Bridged, etc) - if you can't ping the VM address from the windows cmd line (`ping 192.168.65.132`) then you'll not be able to get Eclipse to talk to the VM either. What address is `192.168.65.132` - is that your windows IP address, or the address of the VM?

So to resolve this you're going to need to either re-configure your VM networking and amend your hadoop configuration to use the vm hostname / IP address (that isn't 127.0.0.1), or you may be able to utilize something like PuTTY and create some dynamic IPv4 socks tunnels.

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu i followed micheal-noll and it works .
May be you should try this
http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

Comment: Although your provided link might contain the answer, you should at the very least include a summary, as the community generally agrees that answers should actually contain the answer. Furthermore, the linked website might change its content and become irrelevant.